# Hosting for a Ruby on Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hosting

I am a Ruby on Rails developer and I am planning to purchase an hosting space in order to publish my web application (I'm developing a small Social Network). This is my first time that I try to deploy a Ruby on Rails application, so I am not expert on the matter.

I would like to find a "compromise" between performance and price. I think that for now a shared server it is enough (maybe) for my needs (suggestions are appreciated...).

In localhost I am using

- Ruby on Rails 3.0.9
- ruby-1.9.2-p136
- Apache
- Phusion Passenger
- MySql

so the hosting server should satisfy the above requisites.

More: in my application I am using the Paperclip gem so another requisite should be Image-Magick.

What hosting service do you advice for my needs? What should I have to care when I purchase a hosting space for RoR? And, most importantly, which hosting service do you advice??

P.S.: if you need some other information just ask and I will update the question.

Comment: Why do people want to close the question?

Comment: It's considered OT, look at the first question in the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq. I posted an answer, made it community wiki and will now put in the final vote to close this.

Answer (score 4):

Even though this question is slightly off-topic on SO, I'd recommend you look at Heroku:

http://www.heroku.com/

Hosting a Rails app can't be easier and you can start with the free plan and then scale up as needed.

Comment: What do you mean with "free plan"?

Comment: That it's free to host small apps there. 1 dyno clocks 720h per month and you get 750h for free, so hosting a small app with no add ons doesn't cost you anything. I host 2 Sinatra apps there that way. See: http://www.heroku.com/pricing#1-0

Comment: You say free, but 1 Dyno (I read on the heroku web site) is $36 for month. I think that is to much (per month) for my needs...

Comment: Click the link in my previous answer, top right corner you see the total is $0. I web dyno with no worker dyno costs nothing, if add extra dynos or workers it can become pricey though.